# git check-ignore output empty but still being ignored

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a folder `logs/` which is being ignored:

```
$ $ git status -s --ignored logs
!! logs/
```

But, when I run:

```
git check-ignore -v logs/
```

I get null output, which seems to indicate that there is nothing ignoring it.

I have nothing staged:

```
$ git status --untracked-files=no
On branch master
nothing to commit (use -u to show untracked files)
```

So why is this folder being ignored?

```
$ git --version
git version 2.10.2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens when the ignoring is due to ignoring the file(s) inside the directory, rather than the directory itself.  I made a `logs/` directory and put some things in it and got the same result you got:

```
$ git status -s --ignored logs
!! logs/
```

Here is what I put inside `logs`:

```
$ ls -A logs
foo
```

Here is why it's ignored:

```
$ grep foo .gitignore
foo
```

But here `git check-ignore -v` says nothing about `logs/foo`:

```
$ git check-ignore -v logs/
```

#### Why

Once the directory is "empty" (because all files in it are ignored), it is no longer interesting to Git, since Git does not record directories in commits.  But in this case, it's not the *directory itself* being ignored; it's the summarizing from `git status` that limits you to seeing just the directory here.

Hence, when you ask Git "why is `logs/` ignored", the answer is, sort of, that it's *not* ignored, it's just the *contents* that are ignored.  (I think we could say that this is a bug in `git check-ignore`.)

#### How see what's going on

Add `-uall` (or `--untracked=all`) to see the actual ignored files:

```
$ git status -s --ignored -uall logs
!! logs/foo
$ git check-ignore -v logs/foo
.gitignore:34:logs/foo  logs/foo
```

and now you can find out why the files are being ignored, using their (now no longer summarized away) paths.

(NB: I may have changed the `.gitignore` contents several times above during the cut and paste, which I did piecemeal: at various times I had `logs/foo` and `foo` in `.gitignore`, both of which made the directory "become empty".  So repeating the experiment might give slightly different output.  Nonetheless, the key is using `-uall` to find the file names.)

Comment: Cheers! I found it easier to limit the command to the directory itself: `git status -s --ignored -u all logs` without the `grep` because `logs` appeared in other pathnames. Perhaps you could update the answer?

Comment: @TomHale: I did that, plus some general wording cleanup.